# Issue in populating KO Observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have to display a template in many pages. I am trying to use knockout.

I have a index.html file with following content:

```
<head>
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div id='div1' data-bind="template: {name: 'testTemplate'}"></div>
  </header>
 </body>
```

testTemplate.html is as follows:

```
<div>        
  <button data-bind="click:function(data){$root.test(data)}">Test</button>  
  <!-- ko foreach: globalNavItems -->           
  <p> <a data-bind="text: label, attr:{href: url}"> <span class=""></span> 
    </a></p>        
  <!-- /ko -->     
  </div>
```

I want globalNavItems to be populated on click of button Test.
My main.js is as follows:

```
require(['knockout', 'jquery',  'text!../patterntemplates/testTemplate.html'],       
 function(ko, $, t0)        {          
   function headerViewModel() { 
   var self=this;   
   self.globalNavItems =ko.observableArray([]);                    



self.test = function(data){
         global_nav_dropdown_items =  
                                                                                             ko.observableArray([{"label":                                                                                   "preferences","url":"Menu.html"},                
 {"label": "help","url": "#"},                
 {"label": "about","url": "#"},
 {"label": "sign out","url": "#"}]);
        self.globalNavItems=global_nav_dropdown_items;
      }        


      }           
      oj.koStringTemplateEngine.install();           
      ko.templates["testTemplate"] = t0;           
      $(document).ready(function() {             
        ko.applyBindings(new headerViewModel(),                    
        document.getElementById('div1'));           
        });         
        });
```

I can see the button on while running index.html. On click of the button the method test is also invoked but globalNavItems is not populated and i cannot see any link displayed in my page.

Any pointer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problematic one:

```
self.globalNavItems=global_nav_dropdown_items;
```

By running this, you're replacing the defined `observableArray` with just a plain JavaScript array, and it's no longer bound to the page.  You need to update the observable through it's interface, rather than just assigning to the variable:

```
self.globalNavItems(global_nav_dropdown_items);
```

Comment: Yes, that works but I had to define global_nav_dropdown_items as a normal array and not observable array. If I define global_nav_dropdown_items as a ko observable array as shown in the example, self.globalNavItems(global_nav_dropdown_items); doesn't work.

Comment: ah sorry - had missed that as the definition was scrolled off the side :)  Yes - it's just a normal array to be passed in.  Same thing applies either way - as soon as you assign something new to `self.globalNavItems`, it's no longer the observable that the page was originally bound to, so the bindings don't pick up on changes.  That's something to watch for with knockout - if you find yourself assigning to something that should be observable, it's _probably_ wrong :)